# "Out of Stack Space" while populating jsTree through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have to populate my jsTree with data coming from DB through ajax call. The sample data looks like below data. If you look closely second node(Node2) is the child of first node (Node1) and third node is child of second node but third node's id is **Node2**. Which is creating problem and instead of showing a tree its showing me ...loading... sign.

```
 $('#tree').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : [                  
                { "id" : "Node1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node" },
                { "id" : "Node2", "parent" : "Node1", "text" : "Child 1" },
                { "id" : "Node2", "parent" : "Node2", "text" : "Child 2" },
            ]
        }
    });
```

my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/3re8k7hv/10/) here pls.

Its just a sample data. The actual data contains numbers in ID part and I am using that ID further to fetch more data onSelection event of that node.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo  in your JS code : two node shares the same `id`.

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : [                  
            { "id" : "Node1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node" },
            { "id" : "Node2", "parent" : "Node1", "text" : "Child 1" },
            { "id" : "Node3", "parent" : "Node2", "text" : "Child 2" },
        ]
    }
});
```

Here is a Codepen with working code: http://codepen.io/adrenalinedj/pen/VarWrp

Comment: Hey thats not typo. Thats the problem. I mentioned the same in my description as well that two Nodes have same value in their ID part.

Comment: You can't make it work with nodes with same `id`. Id is something that must be unique.

Comment: Yes, I added some extra unique text to each ID and their respective parents text too.

Comment: So, can you "close" the question, pls ?

Comment: Done. Will accept the same in 2 days. SO's constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I am populating the tree through one AJAX call which brings data in JSON format from my Spring controller. So while preparing the JSON objects I am creating objects in such a way that will make my tree id's unique with their respective parents id too in loop.

Apology for not posting the sample code here because of company policy constrains.